# When is it proper to add a return at the end of a JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have seen some developers place a return at the end of their JavaScript functions like this:

```
$(".items").each(function(){
    mthis = $(this);
    var xposition = some .x() position value;
    if(xposition < 0){
        mthis.remove();
        return;
    }
});
```

Is having a return even necessary?  I know that `return false` cancels out of a loop early and I know that `return x`, returns a value, but having just return??? What does that mean?

Sorry - I forgot to put an end } at the very end of the code.  the return is in the if conditional.

---

**New Update - just discovered that the intent of the loop was to cancel out the nth .item that entered the loop. so return false is my replacement for a simple return; (which means undefined anyway).  Thanks everyone for the  help!**

Comment: I haven't a clue about why people would do this (unless it's some insistence on always having a `return` statement), but `return;` at the end of the function body is precisely the same as omitting it.

Comment: you won't likely get better answers than [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3717420/944681)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example is specific for how `jQuery.each` handles the return values from a loop function. From the docs:

> We can break the $.each() loop at a particular iteration by making the
>   callback function return false. Returning non-false is the same as a
>   continue statement in a for loop; it will skip immediately to the next
>   iteration.

So there you have it, returning anything else than `false` makes no difference, it will just move on to the next iteration. `false`, however, breaks the loop.

Note that `return;` is exactly the same as `return undefined;`.

Answer (score 3):

Having return with not proceeding it at the end of the function doesn't really do anything.  Returning "this" however allows for method chaining.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a way to end the function execution without necessarily having to choose a proper return value. At the end of the function it really doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Just like `return false`, it'll cancel out of the block (in this case, the function) early. The return value will be `undefined`.

At the end of a function, it's equivalent to not using a return statement at all, but your example doesn't look like the end of a function to me.

**EDIT:** Just to make it a bit clearer: This particular return statement is at the end of the surrounding `if` clause, not the function as a whole. In other words, the condition of the `if` clause specifies a situation in which the function should terminate mid-way.

**EDIT 2:** By "the function", I refer to the inner, anonymous function. `return;`, being equivalent to `return undefined;`, will indeed cause `jQuery.each()` to move on to the next item. (Also, it seems that I was mistaken about there being more code in the function; given the OP's edit to the code sample, it really does look like a pointless return statement.)

Comment: That is not true, `return false` in jQuery.each will break the loop. `return;` or `return undefined;` will continue the loop.

Comment: @David Good point. I was referring to the inner, anonymous function, though, as opposed to jQuery.each(). I will make another edit to remove any ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your opening and closing `{ }` braces don't line up, so depending on which is correct, this will perform differently. If the closing brace for the if is after the return, then this will act like a `continue` in a regular for loop.

```
$(".items").each(function(){
    mthis = $(this);
    var xposition = some .x() position value;
    if (xposition < 0) {
        mthis.remove();
        return;
    }
}
```

As it turns out, a `continue` at the end of a for loop is also implicit, so this doesn't really serve a purpose.

Of course, if you're question is more theoretical, the answer is that generally it doesn't make a difference:

```
function doSomething() {
    alert("Hello, world");
    return; //purely a matter of preference
}
```

Here, the method would implicitly return even without the direct invocation of `return` by virtue of being at the end of the code-block; in some cases it can be useful just as an indicator that you are at the end of the function, particular if there was a lot of nesting. If not at the bottom, it definitely makes a difference, since nothing after the `return;` will be executed. Otherwise the difference is purely stylistic. Saves you a few characters to leave it out of course!

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour of return; anywhere in your function is exactly the same as when the code reaches the end of your function, the caller receives undefined.

In that code it's used together with a condition. I would have to assume that you didn't show the full code.

This method is used often to jump to the end of the function when a pre-condition is not met as it might be more readable than five indentations, each with another condition.

Comment: yes, yes and yes.  You are right jack.  I just corrected the issue.  so based on your thoughts, it still doesn't matter....ok that sounds good to me!

Comment: I just got done emailing the developer.  he told me that he is not trying to abort the each() function with a return false, but simply wants to remove the current .item that is in the loop if it meets the conditional statement, then move on to the next .item that comes into the .each function.  in that case would it then make sense to use a return; like i have above?

Comment: You can see the code that I'm talking about if you go here - http://gamequeryjs.com/demos/3/tutorial.js and search the code towards the mid section of the page for $(".enemy").each(function(){... you will then see the return; I am talking about.

Comment: I just discovered that using return false; produces the same results I am looking. so no need for simply return; in the if conditional statement.  Thanks Jack for all the tips!

Comment: @blachawk return false; is not the same because that would also stop the .each()

Comment: I thought the same thing initially Jack but it's not stopping the .each() in my case.  The current item leaves the DOM by its x position, and the .each loop continues to process to the next item...

Comment: @blachawk then xposition is never a negative number :)

Comment: I know. I checked web console and there are no errors thrown, and the dom continouse to process the .each function().  this is driving me crazy.  if using return false will break the .each function(), how come I'm not seeing the loop stop?