# Return statement is inconsistent with previous usage - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, netbeans

What does this error means?

```
Return statement is inconsistent with previous usage
```

Netbeans show this error when i coded the below (snippet):

```
$.each(ToValidate, function (indexOfQuestions, questionNumber) {
    var radioValue = "ja";

    if (radioValue === "NEI" && questionNumber === "1.1") {
        return false;
    } else if (radioValue === "JA" && questionNumber === "1.1") {
        return;
    }
});
```

in `else if`, I am trying to continue the `each`, so I am using `return`. In `if` I need to break the control out of `each` so I am using `return false`. But that error is quite confusing.

Have I used keywords correctly or is there any other way to use Continue and Break in JQuery?

Comment: It probably means your editor thinks it makes more sense to return `true` and not just `undefined`, which I tend to agree with.

Comment: `return;` is the JavaScript equivalent of "return nothing from a void function" (it actually returns undefined implicitly). It's not actually an *error*, but a *warning* - specify the return value explicitly (is it really supposed to be undefined?) to avoid it.

Comment: Also note that the `else` clause is totally useless in that code, it will just return anyway ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a benefit to using a return statement that returns nothing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717420/is-there-a-benefit-to-using-a-return-statement-that-returns-nothing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is documented in NetBeans wiki: [link](http://wiki.netbeans.org/JavaScript_returninconsistent).

What this means is that a caller of the function can't expect a single type of return value which complicates using the function.

Having said that, in the current context that is completely valid code, since $.each only cares if the return value is false.

Answer (score 0):

This is a code checking function noticing that you're returning a value in one code path and not returning a value in another code path in the same function.  Usually, you either want to return a value or not return a value from a given function, not sometimes one and sometimes the other.

So, it is warning you about that unusual (and likely wrong) condition.